# After Downloading Android Studio 3.0 I am unable to compile my Projects in Android Studio 2.3.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After Installing the Android Studio 3.0 Canary 4 I am unable to build the project in it and even I am unable to build the project in my old version of Android Studio 2.3.2

I have tried the following points

1. Added this line at **gradle.properties** -  **gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m**
2. tried Deleting the .gradle folder
3. Tried to run Android Studio as admin
4. Tried this also **File>Invalidate Caches/Restart.**

This is the screenshot [image: screenshot]

Any help is appreciable.
Thanks

> build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.ucssurvey"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: I'd just reinstall Android Studio, and kept only one version of it.

Comment: `rebuild` the project and then hit `try again`
Worked for me

Comment: @Rakshit Add the complete gradle screenshot with your question

Comment: @SuhaylSH : Added the build file

Comment: @VladMatvienko : After downloading the Android Studio 3.0 it installed some files, after that I am unable to build anything

Comment: have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: @VladMatvienko : I am on it

Comment: Which version of gradle are you using? Seems you are on 4.0-rc1, go back to 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was happening because my organisation have installed an antivirus which is **Comodo Internet Security** which is **blocking the Firewall** because of that some files are not updating.
After requesting to uninstalling the antivirus the issue is resolved.